# Describe Words that Begin/End with an Apostrophe

Tags: apostrophe

How do you describe words that begin/end with an apostrophe?

For example:

Beginning with  `'`: `'bout`, `'em`, `'cause`

Ending with  `'`: `ol'`, `runnin'`, `jumpin'`

Comment: An apostrophe simply indicates that something is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are known as **contractions**:

> a shortened form of a word or group of words, with the omitted letters often replaced in written English by an apostrophe …

*[Online Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contraction?s=t)*

Comment: Hmm ... Actually, the examples OP adduces here are colloquialisms. _Contractions_ is too broad.

Comment: The Chicago Manual (7.31) simply lists these as contractions (e.g. words like `singin'`), singling out words like "gonna" and "wanna" as colloquialisms (which don't get an apostrophe because there's no obvious place to place one).

Comment: Down with the Chicago Manual!

Comment: Well, the New Oxford Style Manual says the same thing. :p

Comment: Well, what can I tell you. They'll be first against the wall when the revolution comes.

Comment: They'll have their backs against the wall whether we have revolution or devolution (the latter far more likely).

Comment: Some are commonly associated with dialect or colloquial speech, but "'bout" and "'cause" are found in poetry, so they could also be viewed as poetic forms.

Answer (score 2):

I think they are not contractions. I believe they are elisions:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elision

Comment: Can they not be both?

Comment: If you compare the Wikipedia examples of elisions with contractions, you'll see that the examples above more closely resemble the examples of contractions than of elisions.

Comment: My understanding is that contractions are "grammar"--governed by widely accepted standards that apply to both written and spoken language--while elisions are "linguistics," having more to do with pronunciation, morphemes, etc. Many of these are universal (we do not pronounce the "-ed" in "marked," for example, but rather say "markt"). Likewise, we may say "ol'" instead of "old," but, unless we're conveying dialect, we would never elide that "d" when writing. Elisions vary by region, contractions much less so. What's above still look like elisions to me.